# Data passed through segue lost after hitting back button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view, segue

I have two view controllers A and B and a segue from A to B (type: show) through a next button and a segue from B to A (type: show) through back button. I am passing some data through segue A to B. Data is displayed correctly if I just tap next from controller A and go to controller B.

However, If I tap next and go to controller B and hit back and come back to A and then hit next again, it doesn't work. Any ideas whats going on here? Sorry for the confusing language.

Comment: Is your data stored in a property in controller A, and passed to B through `prepareForSegue` ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your "B to A" is wrong, you're using a navigation stack so you should only push (show) when you are moving forwards. When going backwards you should pop off the top (dismiss)

If you keep pushing, the app will continue to just put more and more ViewControllers in memory, which is bad.

I suspect whats happening here is View A initially has the data and passes it to View B. Then when you press your back button it creates a new copy of View A which doesn't have the data and shows that instead of the original View A.

In Short: (A to B :type - show) (B to A :dismiss the current ViewController)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user2877496 in that you should not use a regular segue to go back from B to A as you will be adding "A" onto the stack each time.
I just wished to add that one method to dismiss B and go back to A is by using an Unwind Segue.
The Apple documentation covers this quite well
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you resolve this?  My guess is you put stuff to execute in viewDidLoad (which only runs once at the start of your app) and it needs to be in viewWillAppear so it is called each time you return to your main view controller. Please provide your code for those methods if you require further help.

Comment: I worked around segues and simply used User Defaults to save data.

Comment: Excellent!  Congrats for solving your own problem. You should write that up  as an answer and accept it.